# use namespace instead of folder name

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Say I have a project:

```
foo-bar
  | - lib.rs
  | - ....
```

But I don't want the namespace `foo-bar`, I only want `bar`. Is there anyway to specify this in `lib.rs`? The obvious solution would be to rename `foo-bar` to `bar`, but I can't do that in this case.

Comment: That's a strange project you have. How come the source directory is called `foo-bar` if this is a cargo project? And if it isn't, you need to call rustc with proper arguments to specify the crate name. Or maybe `lib.rs` here is not a crate root?

Comment: @VladimirMatveev The project is a detached clone of it's parent who went cold. I want to continue development but under a different repository name. [rustty](https://github.com/cpjreynolds/rustty) is the parent, [fe-rustty](https://github.com/Syntaf/fe-rustty) is the clone. If people want to integrate fe instead of the dead repo, all they need to do it change the package name.

Comment: Well yes, but in the project you have linked to `lib.rs` is under `src/` directory, not under `foo-bar`. That's what confused me - this may happen if one does not use Cargo for building. If I were you I would have formulated the question slightly differently: how to change the name of the *library crate*, so it would be different from the name of the *Cargo package*. At least, that's what starblue's answer is about and I guess it is what you want, given that you have accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the name of the library in `Cargo.toml`, see the [Cargo documentation](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target).

```
[lib]
# The name of a target is the name of the library that will be generated. This
# is defaulted to the name of the package or project.
name = "foo"
```